# How can I efficiently add strings after abbreviations from an array source?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'd like to add US State names to strings containing US State abbreviations.

For example I'd like to convert an array of strings like:

`Lorem ipsum CA dolor NY sit foo bar`

to:

`Lorem ipsum CA (California) dolor NY (New York) sit any foo bar`

Assume my replacement array looks like so:

```
$states = array(
    "AR" => "Arkansas",
    "CA" => "California",
    "NY" => "New York"
);
```

One way is to do array_key searches:

```
$input = "Lorem ipsum CA dolor NY sit any foo bar";
$words = explode(' ', $input);
foreach ($words as $key => $word) {
    if (array_key_exists($word, $states)) {
        $words[$k] = $word . " (" . $states[$word] . ")";
    }
}
$output = implode(" ", $words);
// Output: Lorem ipsum CA (California) dolor NY (New York) sit any foo bar
```

Is there a more efficient way using native PHP functions or regex?

Solution should not match partial matches (ex. `any` should not match `NY`, and `bar` should not match `AR`).

Comment: Just to raise this issue - how would you deal with something like -  IN - Indiana - how should this work with "I am IN a state?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace_callback` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) you can do this in single step without any loop:

```
$repl = preg_replace_callback('/\b(' . implode("|", array_keys($states)) . ')\b/',
     function ($m) use($states) { return $m[1] . ' (' . $states[$m[1]] . ')'; }, $input);

//=> Lorem ipsum CA (California) dolor NY (New York) sit any foo bar
```

**Code Explanation:**

- `'/\b(' . implode("|", array_keys($states)) . ')\b/'`: Here we are building a regex using array keys taken from array `$states`. It will become: `/\b(AR|CA|NY)\b/` here. Note that state abbreviation is being captured in group #1 in this regex.
- `$m[1] . ' (' . $states[$m[1]] . ')'` is appending name of the state in front of the state abbreviation

Comment: Perfect. This worked with each word individually. If anyone else would like to use this for more complex keys, include `preg_quote()` to escape the regex special characters. Ex. `$states[preg_quote($m[1], '/')];`

Answer (score 2):

With a slight change to the array format, you can use `strtr()` with the array...

```
$states = array(
    "AR" => "AR (Arkansas)",
    "CA" => "CA (California)",
    "NY" => "NY (New York)"
);

$text = "Lorem ipsum CA dolor NY sit foo bar";

echo strtr( $text, $states);
```

gives...

```
Lorem ipsum CA (California) dolor NT (New York) sit foo bar
```

Comment: With the caveat that the abbreviations do not appear conjoined with other text, for example "I don't want ANY oranges from CA."

Comment: @bishop There are all sorts of potential problems - IN - Indiana - so how doe this work in "I am IN a state?"

Comment: Note that, internally, this will probably be the fastest solution: strtr is optimized for key replacement where the keys are all the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to split the words, just loop through the states and replace the short state to the new text.

This should do the work:

```
$states = array(
    "AR" => "Arkansas",
    "CA" => "California",
    "NY" => "New York"
);

$input = "Lorem ipsum CA dolor NY sit any foo bar";
foreach($states as $shortState=>$longState){
   $input = str_replace($shortState, $shortState." (".$longState.")", $input); 
}
echo $input;
// output: Lorem ipsum CA (California) dolor NY (New York) sit any foo bar
```